# RSA c implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, cryptography, gmp

This is my first attempt to implement a crypto algorithm.

I am using C and [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) to interact with big numbers.

I am basing my implementation of the RSA algorithm from the book "[A handbook of applied cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)" (chapter 8.2)  :

- Take two distinct, large primes `p` and `q`

  - Ideally these have a similar byte-length
- Multiply `p` and `q` and store the result in `n`
- Find the totient for `n` using the formula $$\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$$
- Take an `e` coprime that is greater, than 1 and less than `n`
- Find `d` using the formula $$d\cdot e\equiv1\mod\varphi(n)$$

At this point, the pair `(e, n)` is the public key and the private key `(d, n)` is the private key.

Here is my code; you can run it after having linked with the `-lgmp` parameter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "gmp.h"



void generatePrimes(mpz_t* p, mpz_t* q);
void computeNandF(mpz_t* q, mpz_t* p, mpz_t *phi, mpz_t* n);
void generateE(mpz_t* phi, mpz_t* e);
void enc(mpz_t* e, mpz_t* n, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* c, char[]);
void dec(mpz_t* m, mpz_t* c, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* n);
void makeKeys(mpz_t n, mpz_t e, mpz_t d, mpz_t p, mpz_t q);
void encrFile(mpz_t e, mpz_t n, mpz_t d, mpz_t c);

gmp_randstate_t stat;

int main() {


 mpz_t p, q, phi, e, n, d, c, dc;
 char msg[40] = "welcome to cryptoworld";
 int *mes;
 int len = strlen(msg);
 mpz_init(p);
 mpz_init(q);
 mpz_init(phi);
 mpz_init(e);
 mpz_init(n);
 mpz_init(d);
 mpz_init(c);
 mpz_init(dc);

 // RSA algorithm
 generatePrimes(&p, &q);
 computeNandF(&q, &p, &phi, &n);
 generateE(&phi, &e);
 // extended Euclidean
 mpz_invert(d, e, phi);
 printf("d = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, d);
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


 enc(&e, &n, &d, &c, msg);

 dec(&dc, &c, &d, &n);

 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("encrypt message  = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, c);
 printf("\n");
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("message as int after decr  = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, dc);
 printf("\n");


 mpz_export(mes, (size_t*) malloc(sizeof (size_t)), 1, sizeof (mes[0]), 0, 0, dc);
 char r[40];
 printf("message as string after decr  = ");
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     r[i] = (char) mes[i];
     printf("%c", r[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");

 encrFile(e, n, d, c);

 mpz_clear(p);
 mpz_clear(q);
 mpz_clear(phi);
 mpz_clear(n);
 mpz_clear(e);
 mpz_clear(c);
 mpz_clear(d);
 mpz_clear(dc);
 return 0;
}

void generatePrimes(mpz_t* p, mpz_t* q) {

 int primetest;
 long sd = 0;
 mpz_t seed;
 gmp_randinit(stat, GMP_RAND_ALG_LC, 120);
 mpz_init(seed);
 srand((unsigned) getpid());
 sd = rand();
 mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
 gmp_randseed(stat, seed);


 mpz_urandomb(*p, stat, 512);
 primetest = mpz_probab_prime_p(*p, 10);
 if (primetest != 0) {
    printf("p is prime\n");
 } else {
    //printf("p wasnt prime,choose next prime\n");
    mpz_nextprime(*p, *p);
 }

 mpz_urandomb(*q, stat, 512);
 primetest = mpz_probab_prime_p(*q, 10);
 if (primetest != 0) {
    // printf("q is prime\n");
 } else {
    // printf("p wasnt prime,choose next prime\n");
    mpz_nextprime(*q, *q);
 }


 printf("p and q generated!!\n");
 printf("p = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, *p);
 printf("q = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, *q);
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 mpz_clear(seed);
 return;
}

void computeNandF(mpz_t* q, mpz_t* p, mpz_t *phi, mpz_t* n) {

 mpz_t temp1, temp2;
 mpz_init(temp1);
 mpz_init(temp2);
 //n=p*q
 mpz_mul(*n, *q, *p);
 mpz_sub_ui(temp1, *q, 1); //temp1=q-1
 mpz_sub_ui(temp2, *p, 1); //temp2=p-1
 //φ=(p-1)(q-1)
 mpz_mul(*phi, temp1, temp2);
 printf("phi and n generated!!\n");
 printf(" n= ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, *n);
 printf("phi = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, *phi);
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

void generateE(mpz_t* phi, mpz_t* e) {

 mpz_t temp, seed;
 mpz_init(seed);
 mpz_init(temp);
 long sd = 0;
 gmp_randinit(stat, GMP_RAND_ALG_LC, 120);
 srand((unsigned) getpid());
 sd = rand();
 mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
 gmp_randseed(stat, seed);

 do {
    mpz_urandomm(*e, stat, *phi + 1);
    mpz_gcd(temp, *phi, *e); //temp=gcd(e,φ)
 } while (mpz_cmp_ui(temp, 1) != 0); //while gcd!=1
 printf("e generated \n e = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, *e);
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

 }

void enc(mpz_t* e, mpz_t* n, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* c, char msg[]) {

 int r[40];
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++) {
    r[i] = (int) msg[i];
 }

 int *m = r;
 mpz_t M;
 mpz_init(M);
 mpz_import(M, strlen(msg), 1, sizeof (m[0]), 0, 0, m);
 printf("message as int before encryption  = ");
 mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, M);
 printf("\n");

 mpz_powm(*c, M, *e, *n);

}

void dec(mpz_t* m, mpz_t* c, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* n) {

  mpz_powm(*m, *c, *d, *n);

}

void encrFile(mpz_t e, mpz_t n, mpz_t d, mpz_t c) {

  char text[80];
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  if (file) {
     while ((x = getc(file)) != EOF) {
         i++;
         putchar(x);
         text[i] = (char) x;
     }
   
    int r[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        r[i] = (int) text[i];
    }

    int *m = r;
    mpz_t M;
    mpz_init(M);
    mpz_import(M, strlen(text), 1, sizeof (m[0]), 0, 0, m);
    printf("message as int before encryption  = ");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, M);
    printf("\n");
  
    mpz_powm(c, M, e, n);
    printf("encrypt txt  = ");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, c);
    printf("\n");
 
    fclose(file);
    file = fopen("text.txt", "w");
  
    mpz_out_raw(file, c);
    fclose(file);

  }

}
```

Any comments and improvements in my implementation will be appreciated.

Comment: From what library is "gmp.h"?

Comment: Can you explain more about what this code is supposed to do and whether it does so in a satisfactory manner? There are a lot of variable names which could use an explanation, the initialization is odd at best and some of the definitions don't make much sense at first glance.

Comment: @Mast https://gmplib.org/

Comment: @Mast the library is gmp. This code supposed to implement all the steps of RSA(https://amirshenouda.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/image3.png). I have the steps in the methods wich have names to understand the step.  And all my variables have the proper names like the steps of the algorithm (ex. n is the n from the algo)

Comment: Much better already :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Indicate your locals

Since all of your functions are in the same translation unit, make them `static`.

### Passing by reference

Some of your `mpz_t` are explicitly passed by reference, i.e.

```
void generatePrimes(mpz_t* p, mpz_t* q);
```

and some appear initially to be passed by value:

```
void encrFile(mpz_t e, mpz_t n, mpz_t d, mpz_t c);
```

These structures are defined here:

```
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;        /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed
                   to by the _mp_d field.  */
  int _mp_size;         /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the
                   last field points to.  If _mp_size is
                   negative this is a negative number.  */
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;     /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;

typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

Confusingly, even if you don't add a `*`, you will be passing by reference, because `mpz_t` is defined as an array. As such, you should be dropping the pointer notation everywhere.

You really do need to mark `const` the pointer arguments that you don't change, especially since everything is being passed by reference.

### Naming arguments

Function prototypes aren't just to predeclare a function to sort out order dependency. They're also documentation for developers. As such, your unnamed `char[]` argument here:

```
void enc(mpz_t* e, mpz_t* n, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* c, char[]);
```

needs to be named.

### Variable names

I realize that many of these variable names are defined by your book, but that doesn't help other developers (or you in the future). At the absolute least, write a comment beside every variable that you declare describing what it is and how it's used. If possible, upgrade variable names from cryptic single letters to actual words.

### Error checking

All system calls, e.g. to `fopen`, might fail and need to be checked. This:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if (file) {
```

silently ignores failures to open the file, which is bad. You need to do something meaningful - in this case, perhaps `perror("Failed to open crypto file"); exit(1);`

### Combine declaration and initialization

This:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
```

should be

```
FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
```

### Avoid overflows

This segment of code:

```
char text[80];
FILE *file;
file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
int i = 0;
if (file) {
    while ((x = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        i++;
        putchar(x);
        text[i] = (char) x;
    }

    int r[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        r[i] = (int) text[i];
    }
```

is begging for an overflow error in a handful of ways. You have a fixed-length `text` array to which you write file contents with no length check other than EOF. You also have an `r` array whose initialization loop ignores its length and relies on `strlen` - but you haven't null-terminated your `text` string!

Instead,

1. Get the length of the file.
2. Don't even bother with initializing a character array; skip to initializing your `int` array.
3. Dynamically allocate the array with `malloc` based on the size of the file.
4. Read into the array until it's full.

### Don't use `printf` unless you have to

This:

```
printf("message as int before encryption  = ");
```

doesn't do any formatting, so use `puts` instead, which is more efficient.

### Make your file I/O functions more flexible

Don't hardcode the file name `text.txt`. Instead, accept that as an argument to the function. Get it from user input or a command-line argument.

Comment: Usually `printf()` with one argument (at least if not containing format specifiers) usually gets optimized into a `puts()` call, at least gcc+glibc does that.

Comment: @larkey I'd offer that since both `printf` and `puts` are available to the user, and it's no extra effort to use `puts`, it's both useful and educational to use the latter. But that's good to know!

Comment: Sure!  Often I end up using `printf()` even for simple things since I just edit something away and don't bother to change or have some logging macro, though.

Comment: Why show `typedef struct { ... } __mpz_struct;`? Type `mpz_t` is an array and `encrFile(mpz_t e, mpz_t n, mpz_t d, mpz_t c)` receives pointers (to the first element of `mpz_t`).  Even if `__mpz_struct` was huge, `encrFile()` would still receive 4 pointers.

Comment: @chux That's straight from the header file. Interesting - so `mpz_t` is an array? If so, the OP shouldn't be using pointers anywhere.

Comment: As I see it, using type `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];` allows _most_ `mpz_...()` to fake a call by reference as  with `mpz_t p; ...  mpz_init(p);`.  Unfortunately it does not apply to `rop` in `mpz_export (void *rop, ...` and so [messes up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210824/29485) OP code.

Comment: @chux OK, well valid points; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Invalid code**

In `while ((x = getc(file)) != EOF)`, where is `x` defined? <sup>1</sup>

```
error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

**Use of uninitialized object**

The pointer `mes` is passed to `mpz_export()` without initialization/assignment.

```
int *mes;
...
// Garbage value pass to  `mpz_export(void *rop, ...)`
mpz_export(mes, (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t)), 1, sizeof(mes[0]), 0, 0,
...
r[i] = (char) mes[i];
```

The compiler warning hinted to this problem.  This implies code is not using a good compiler will all warnings enabled.  Save time.  Enable then all.

```
warning: 'mes' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

I suspect the following will fix

```
//int *mes;
//int len = strlen(msg);
int len = strlen(msg);
int mes[len + !len]; // Insure VLA is at least size 1

// Unsure about mpz_export() repair needs.
// mpz_export(mes, (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t)), 1, sizeof(mes[0]), 0, 0, dc);
mpz_export(   mes,           malloc(sizeof(size_t)), 1, sizeof mes    , 0, 0, dc);
```

**Passing by reference cheat**

The `mpz` library **cheats**.

`typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];` defines `mpz_t` as an array of 1.

Consider the following:

```
extern void foo(mpz_t arg1);
mpz_t a;
foo(a);
```

In common C, one would **not** expect `a` to be modified by `foo()` as C is *pass by value* .  Yet since `a` is an array of `__mpz_struct`, `a` is converted from its value as an array to the addresses of `a[0]`.  It is that address that is passed by value to  `foo`.  Now `foo()` can change the caller's `a`.

To prevent/allow changing `mpz_t` augments, the `mpz` library uses `const`.

```
//       can change,     can't change,    can't change,    can't change
mpz_powm (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t base, const mpz_t exp, const mpz_t mod)
```

But what should OP's function do?  Take advantage of the hidden "call-by-reference"?

Consider OP's `dec()`

```
void dec(mpz_t* m, mpz_t* c, mpz_t* d, mpz_t* n) {
  mpz_powm(*m, *c, *d, *n);
}
```

This should use `const` to indicate which may change.

```
void dec_alt1(mpz_t* m, const mpz_t* c, const mpz_t* d, const mpz_t* n) {
  mpz_powm(*m, *c, *d, *n);
}
```

It is quite unnecessary to pass 4 `mpz_t*` pointers. Code could have been the following which is also passing 4 pointers.

```
void dec_alt2(mpz_t m, const mpz_t c, const mpz_t d, const mpz_t n) {
  mpz_powm(m, c, d, n);
}
```

Alternatively, code could avoided the hidden "pass-by-reference":

```
void dec_alt3(mpz_t *m, const mpz_t c, const mpz_t d, const mpz_t n) {
  mpz_powm(*m, c, d, n);
}
```

**Avoid casual sign changes**

Code could have easily called `mpz_set_si (mpz_t rop, signed long int op)` rather  than `mpz_set_ui (mpz_t rop, unsigned long int op)` and avoided a warning:

```
warning: 
conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'long int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

This implies the compilation was not done with `-Wsign-conversion` or its equivalent.

Casual sign-ness changes are a source of bugs. Save time and enable the warning to help weed code of causal changes.  There are at least 4 in OP's code.

```
long sd = 0;
sd = rand();
// mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
mpz_set_si(seed, sd);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This error makes code not compilable, one of the reasons for closing the question.  Let us count this as a copy/paste error. Still, better to be certain that the code *posted* compiles, not just the code on your computer.